# Getting jQuery to work on rails app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

My page worked locally before when it was just a static html page with jQuery.  However, I built it on top of rails because I wanted free web hosting on heroku.

All I did was move the jQuery into the application.js file and changed the application.html.erb file because that's all that's needed, right?

I have the following included in my gemfile:

```
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'thor'
```

Here's my Application.html.erb file:

```
      <head>
          <title>Me</title>
            <%= stylesheet_link_tag :all %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag  "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag  "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "jquery-rails.js" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "jquery.easing-1.3.pack.js" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js" %>
  <%= render 'layouts/stylesheets' %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
        </head>
```

And this is my application.js file:

```
// Place your application-specific JavaScript functions and classes here
// This file is automatically included by javascript_include_tag :defaults

            $("a#example1").fancybox();

            $("a#example2").fancybox({
                'overlayShow'   : false,
                'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
                'transitionOut' : 'elastic'
            });

            $("a#example3").fancybox({
                'transitionIn'  : 'none',
                'transitionOut' : 'none'    
            });

            $("a#example4").fancybox({
                'opacity'       : true,
                'overlayShow'   : false,
                'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
                'transitionOut' : 'none'
            });

            $("a#example5").fancybox();

            $("a#example6").fancybox({
                'titlePosition'     : 'outside',
                'overlayColor'      : '#000',
                'overlayOpacity'    : 0.9
            });

            $("a#example7").fancybox({
                'titlePosition' : 'inside'
            });

            $("a#example8").fancybox({
                'titlePosition' : 'over'
            });

            $("a[rel=example_group]").fancybox({
                'transitionIn'      : 'none',
                'transitionOut'     : 'none',
                'titlePosition'     : 'over',
                'titleFormat'       : function(title, currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts) {
                    return '<span id="fancybox-title-over">Image ' + (currentIndex + 1) + ' / ' + currentArray.length + (title.length ? ' &nbsp; ' + title : '') + '</span>';
                }
            });

            /*
            *   Examples - various
            */

            $("#various1").fancybox({
                'titlePosition'     : 'inside',
                'transitionIn'      : 'none',
                'transitionOut'     : 'none'
            });

            $("#various2").fancybox();

            $("#various3").fancybox({
                'width'             : '75%',
                'height'            : '75%',
                'autoScale'         : false,
                'transitionIn'      : 'none',
                'transitionOut'     : 'none',
                'type'              : 'iframe'
            });

            $("#various4").fancybox({
                'padding'           : 0,
                'autoScale'         : false,
                'transitionIn'      : 'none',
                'transitionOut'     : 'none'
            });
        });
```

Comment: Did you check that the correct .js files are being handed to the browser when the page is requested? Firebug in Firefox will show you this quickly. Or can you explain better what "not working" means?

Comment: Interesting.  It says uncaught type error: object#<object> has no method 'fancybox'.

Comment: You need to include fancybox.js ... you are missing that

Comment: Thought you hit the spot, but that didn't work. The js files are all under public/js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove

> ```
> <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
> ```

Because that adds prototype (in case you are still with ~ 2.x to 3.0.x).

Also it seems you are trying to use fancybox but have not included the necessary JS file for fancybox.

First copy the `jquery.fancybox-x.x.x.pack.js` to `public/js/`
Then include this tag

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery.fancybox-x.x.x.pack.js" %>
```

Comment: that wasn't it unfortunately.

Comment: But I do understand the conflict that involves prototype and jQuery. I removed it anyways to prevent future conflict.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried wrapping all these functions in a

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  // your scripts here

});
```

your scripts may have worked locally only because the page was loaded fast enough for the script to find your content already there. Oh, and if you removed `javascript_include_tag :default` you have to include the `application.js` by yourself.

Comment: hmmm, good solution but unfortunately it didn't work out.  I think I'm going to get a solid understand of jQuery with rails before I tackle this issue again.

Comment: weird. better use firebug or chrome dev tools to see what's going on... if you're on rails 3.1, i heard the assets pipeline can generate strange effects with scripts... maybe a lead ?